# Why is transform not doing what it is supposed to in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first time using Unity and I don't get why my code won't set the position of the Main Camera.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionDetect : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 CameraPosition;
    void Start()
    {
        CameraPosition = this.transform.position;
    }
    void Reset()
    {
        CameraPosition.x = 520.64f;
        CameraPosition.z = 491.4f;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
        {
            Reset();
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        this.transform.position = CameraPosition;
    }
}
```

I tried using the if statement in the Update() function but it didn't work either. I did all of the ways I could think of and nothing.

Comment: so you set a variable called cameraposition to whatever object this script is running on.  If you trigger something successfully on the thing this is and it hits something with a tag of Cube, it will place the variable at a specific position.. an din update, it changes this, whatever this object is, to either that original position or that "reset" posiiton. ..  What is "this" object, how is it moving, does it meet the trigger requirements, what did debugging tell you? What makes you think this moves a camera?

Comment: OnTriggerEnter Did is worked ?

Comment: It will work with any other code and I only added the start and update functions to change camera position. I can use Destroy(this.gameObject) instead of Reset() and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

i pinpointed to your problem
You wana reset the camera position at triggerEnter but this is not happening
Because at start

void Start()

{

CameraPosition = this.transform.position;

```
}
```

you are setting camera position to the gameObject (gameobject with CollisionDetect Script ) and in Update loop void Update()
{
this.transform.position = CameraPosition;
} you are setting gameObject (gameobject with CollisionDetect Script ) position to the position of camera

this means that you are setting the both gameobject and camera on same position all the time  , Reset functions runs but on the very next frame it again comes to update position

can you tell your exacty scenario to match the correct logic